# Pasar información de un label a un gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo este grid en asp.net c#

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdmntoestibaEmbarquea" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="10%" showheader="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
         >
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Artículo" >
            <ItemTemplate>                                                  
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TxtArticulo"   runat="server" Width="40" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantidad">
                <ItemTemplate>                                              
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCantidad" Visible="true" runat="server" Width="40" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="desp">
                <ItemTemplate>                                              
                      <asp:Label ID="LblDescripcion" Visible="true" runat="server" Width="40" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>   
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

y de esta forma pongo los valores de TxtArticulo y TxtCantidad. y al momento de poner la información del lbl no me pone ya que no la traigo de la base de datos si no que ya la informacion la tiene el label.

de esta manera pongo la informacion en el gridview

```
        grdmntoestibaEmbarquea.DataSource = vDataSet.Tables[0];
        grdmntoestibaEmbarquea.DataBind();

        for (int i = 0; i < grdmntoestibaEmbarquea.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            ((TextBox)grdmntoestibaEmbarquea.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("TxtArticulo")).Text = vDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SE_Codigo_Articulo"].ToString();

            ((TextBox)grdmntoestibaEmbarquea.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TxtCantidad")).Text = vDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SE_Cantidad_Embarcada"].ToString();


            ((Label)grdmntoestibaEmbarquea.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("LblDescripcion")).Text.Trim();


        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no estaría entendiendo el problema

Comment: Me explico: Tengo dos inpust uno que al ingresarle un numero del articulo me trae la descricion en un label  y otro que es para ingresarle la cantidad, al momento de darle en el boton guardar el me pone la informacion en el grid pero no se como pasarle la informacion que tengo en el label.

Comment: ahhh.. tu dataset no esta trayendo la descripcion?

Comment: Con la imagen puede que entiendas mas, cuando pongo el numero del articulo y le doy enter el me trae la descripción, pero cuando le doy en el boton embarcar necesito ponerla en el gridview sin necesidad de consultar la base de datos por que ya traje la descipción

Comment: @EduardZora, necesitarías de alguna manera saber a cuál fila le pertenece ese valor del label. En teoría, podrías recorrer nuevamente las filas del GridView: `for (int i = 0; i < grdmntoestibaEmbarquea.Rows.Count; i++)...` y en esta línea la cambias así: `((Label)grdmntoestibaEmbarquea.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("LblDescripcion")).Text = textbox1.Text;` = donde `textbox1` es el control de ASP.NET que tiene la información a colocar.

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente error   `Error 92 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que asignas un DataSource en el grid pero porque no usas esto para asignar los datos

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtArticulo"   runat="server" Width="40" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Eval("SE_Codigo_Articulo") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

si los datos provienen del datatable deberias bidearlo directo, analiza donde se usa `Text='<%# Eval("SE_Codigo_Articulo") %>'`

El valor que no proviene del datatable deberias asignarlo en el evento [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)
este evento se procuce por cada row que se crea, entonces es alli donde tienes cceso y asignas el valor al label.

Comment: +1 No me acordaba del `Eval`.